# Reinstalling with mysql data files

Tags: mysql

We lost our windows 2012 OS through a soft mirror problem but it looks like we still have the disk files.

Our backup is from the night before but if I can recover from the data files themselves, that would be great.

How would I go about it, if possible?

Comment: Do you have the .dump files? Or .txt, .csv files with all data in it? Use `C:\> mysql -u root -p

mysql> create database mydb;
mysql> use mydb;
mysql> source db_backup.dump;` or `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/filename.txt' INTO TABLE tablename;`

Comment: I was thinking of installing MySQL and then copying the data and configuration files back. Would that not work?

Comment: See if [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/250559/how-to-restore-mysql-database-from-the-physical-files) helps you in that case.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was thinking and good to know it is possible.

Comment: Cool, I will put that in the answer then for future.

Comment: MySQL isn't really something to be 'installed'. My 'installation' resides on a small USB stick plugged into my monitor

Comment: I ran the installer, which created the uninstaller and the services. Then I copied the old data files over and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible as per [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/250559/how-to-restore-mysql-database-from-the-physical-files) post. That should help you out.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to find out the exact windows version that was installed?

Comment: Looked at the version of the exe and got the version